# Programing response to 'any key to continue'

Tags: bash, user-input, stdin

**Scenario:** There are a large number of repositories and 3rd party programs which I install whenever I freshly install Linux on my machine, and the process (including config) often takes half a day. I install these programs using the `Advanced Package Tool`, and I'm trying to automate this process.

**Problem:** APT will usually prompt the user to input the keypress 'Y', to confirm an installation, and I am wondering how I would use a Bash script to automate this keypress so that the script can proceed with installation without any human interaction.

Example of keypress:

> ```
> 0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to remove and 8 not to upgrade.
> Need to get 202 kB of archives.
> After this operation, 736 kB of additional disk space will be used.
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
> ```

**Specifications:** I have considered condensing all the `apt-get` installations into a single `apt-get` system call (which is possible), however I want the program to record the success of each installation by monitoring return codes.

I should specify; the keypress will occur during the execution of the system call for: `apt-get install **application**`, and I am unsure whether another scripting language such as `Ruby` or `Python` might not be better suited to this task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get` very specifically has a `-y` option to allow you to bypass interactive prompting.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just use

```
yes | sudo apt-get install ...
```

Of course, you need to have it set up so that you don't have to enter your password.

Comment: running the script as sudo should do it, thanks.